# Does performing research in the lab or academy permanently reduce ecobalance in Anno 2070?

Tags: anno-2070

I've been conducting a lot of research in my labs and academies.  I noticed that the ecobalance goes down during research and somehow it doesn't go back to previous level when research is done.  Is that the cost of performing too many research? Does the ecobalance ever go back to previous level?

I was performing simultaneous research on 3 academies and 3 labs.

Comment: I've never noticed that aspect.  I may have to fire the game up to test.

Comment: Are you sure this is due to the research? If so: are you sure you made nothing else? Researching increases energy cost, you might have unconciously placed an energy production building that decreases ecobalance. Since I do not believe labs/academies reduce ecobalance.

Comment: I only build solar panels, they don't decrease ecobalance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ecobalance dips while researching, but it should return to the original levels after the research is over. Is it possible that you built some other structure or started a new process while the research was going on that has a constant ecobalance reduction?